# Go To XY not working on one map but works on other maps using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, xy

I'm not sure what I did to cause this issue as it worked previously. When I attempt to use the "go to XY" feature on ArcGIS Pro v. 2.9.3 it seems to work fine when I try on a new map template, but on my current template it doesn't seem to work. I can type in the coordinates and it will direct me to the point and flash green, but I am no longer able to mark the waypoint. I have looked online for answers and haven't seemed to find anything.

Why might this be happening?

Comment: In ArcMap, this is usually due to map annotation group issues, such as having them turned off or set to another targeted annotation group.  Not sure about Pro.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your map has different Coordinate System than the other, so the  "XY" (lat,long) is different for that CRS.